# problem with shared memory

Tags: c, gcc, shared-memory

Tried to create shared memory block, and what I got is strange behaviour.

```
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include "stdio.h"
#include <sys/ipc.h>

int main() {
printf("starting\n");

int mid = -1;
mid = shmget((key_t)1234, 4096, IPC_CREAT|0666);
if(mid == -1) {
    printf("cant get mid\n");
    return 1;
} else {
    printf("got mid");
}

int* maddr = 0;
maddr = shmat(mid, NULL ,0);
if(maddr == (int*)-1) {
    printf("cant attach memory\n");
    return 1;
} else {
    printf("got maddr");
}

while(1) {
    int cval = __sync_add_and_fetch(maddr, 1);
    if(cval % 2) { // odd values
            printf("messager 1");
            sleep(1000);
    }
}
}
```

If I try to execute that code, it prints starting and hangs, nothing more happens, but some why it accepts input from stdin, so I can print just like if scanf is running

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`stdout` is line-buffered by default, which means that it is not flushed until a newline is printed.  This means that you need to put `\n` at the end of your `"got mid"`, `"got maddr"` and `"messager 1"` strings, or `fflush();` after those `printf()`s.

By the way, SYSV shared memory is outdated.  The POSIX mechanisms are significantly better designed - see `shm_open()` and related calls.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding a new line (`\n`) at the end of *all* of your `printf` statements. I assume it's failing  before printing/flushing the buffer.

You can enter things in because the terminal is not blocking keystrokes, even though you haven't paused anywhere to read it. I regularly type in the "next thing" while my command-line/terminal is busy doing something else so that it just picks up when it's done. The stdin buffer can still accept the input. It just doesn't use it yet.